# Jetson TX2 device tree, i2c nodes and camera driver loading

Tags: drivers, nvidia, devices, embedded, device-tree

I am a bit confused with behavior of Jetson TX2 when loading drivers for camera.

Here is definition of IMX274 in device tree:

```
i2c@3180000 {
        reg = <0x0 0x3180000 0x0 0x100>;
        dmas = <0x19 0x17 0x19 0x17>;
        interrupts = <0x0 0x1b 0x4>;
        compatible = "nvidia,tegra186-i2c";
        clock-names = "div-clk", "parent", "slow-clk";
        reset-names = "i2c";
        clock-frequency = <0x61a80>;
        scl-gpio = <0x12 0x72 0x0>;
        sda-gpio = <0x12 0x73 0x0>;
        clocks = <0xd 0x4b 0xd 0x10d 0xd 0x5c>;
        resets = <0xd 0x15>;
        status = "okay";
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        phandle = <0x7c>;
        #stream-id-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x0>;
        dma-names = "rx", "tx";
        linux,phandle = <0x7c>;

        imx274_a@1a {
                reg = <0x1a>;
                mclk = "extperiph1";
                devnode = "video0";
                avdd-reg = "vana";
                compatible = "nvidia,imx274";
                clock-names = "extperiph1", "pllp_grtba";
                reset-gpios = <0x12 0x8d 0x0>;
                physical_h = "2.738";
                physical_w = "3.674";
                clocks = <0xd 0x59 0xd 0x10d>;
                vana-supply = <0x1a>;
                sensor_model = "imx274";
                iovdd-reg = "vif";
                delayed_gain = "true";
                vif-supply = <0x1a>;
                dvdd-reg = "vdig";
                vdig-supply = <0x1a>;

                mode0 {
                    ...
                }

                ports {
                        #address-cells = <0x1>;
                        #size-cells = <0x0>;

                        port@0 {
                                reg = <0x0>;

                                endpoint {
                                        bus-width = <0x4>;
                                        remote-endpoint = <0x1d>;
                                        phandle = <0x94>;
                                        csi-port = <0x0>;
                                        linux,phandle = <0x94>;
                                };
                        };
                };
        };
```

i2c2 is an alias for i2c@3180000 therefore I expect to see the device on bus 2. An sure I can see it on a bus with address `0x57`.

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/kernel/kernel$ sudo i2cdetect -r -y 2
[sudo] password for nvidia: 
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 57 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Here comes the first question. **How does kernel identifies type of i2c device on a bus?** I thought that field `reg` is used, but 0x1a in device tree is clearly different from 0x57 on a bus.

Secondly, as I can see module is compatible with the following drivers: `compatible = "nvidia,imx274";` However device driver is different:

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/kernel/kernel$ sudo v4l2-ctl -D -d /dev/video0
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
        Driver name   : tegra-video
        Card type     : vi-output, imx274 2-001a
        Bus info      : platform:15700000.vi:0
        Driver version: 4.4.38
        Capabilities  : 0x84200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps   : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
```

**Therefore it seems for me that wrong driver is loaded for some reasons, it it true or I am just missing something?** However it is still possible to capture image with argus.

Comment: I'm no expert, so some part is just guessing. For example, I don't know how the driver is connected to the CSI port. The I2C address is probably hardcoded in the driver, because it is fixed to the image sensor. `i2cdetect` does only probe randomly, without knowing the device tree, so no magic here. And are you sure about `compatible = "nvidia,imx274"`, not `"sony,imx274"`? Isn't that a Sony driver?

Comment: @Philippos yep, there is built-in driver in kernel and I am pretty sure about this compatible string, it is just copy-pasted from currently used dtb/dts file. So I2C core just populates all the described devices no matter of their presence? Also still missing why driver is different from that of compatible string.

Comment: 1) As long as the device tree does the correct MUXing for the I2C pins and the naked I2C driver is loaded (which is probably default), `i2cdetect` can probe for devices independent from actual devices being present or higher-level drivers being loaded. Mainly just trying each address and checking for an ACK. 2) To my knowledge, the `compatible` is checked against identifiers different from the driver name. A driver can call itself `foo` but get triggered by `compatible,bar`

Answer (score 0):

some random answers :

reg = <0x1a> in the dts file is the address, not the type, of the peripheral on the i2c bus.  Because that address is registered by the driver, it won't be probed by i2c-detect, hence the 'UU' at address 1a in i2c-detect's output. The '57' in your output is another peripheral.

in nvidia TX2 v4l2 world, /dev/video0 refers to the driver of the VI which is connected to the CSI which your sensor is connected to. 'imx274 2-001a' in the output of 'v4l2-ctl -D' tells you that that VI is connected to a imx274 located on the 2nd (arbitrary linux-kernel ordering) i2c bus, at the address 0x1a.